# Grant IAM user access to API Credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm attempting to give [API Credentials](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) access to a user via IAM. However, I'm unable to find an existing [Predefined Product Role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#predefined_roles) that encapsulates these permissions. The closest I can find is `roles/
iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` under *Service Account* but that only allows me to grant access to:

```
Impersonate service accounts (create OAuth2 access tokens, sign blobs or JWTs, etc).
```

I don't want to create a Service account, but simply another user account which can sign in and manage the OAuth credentials / access keys.

Comment: As per documentation states, API keys should be used for almost all cases with service accounts.
You can check the documentation where I found the info here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys

Answer (score 0):

To be able to create an API Key, the IAM user must have the Editor role `roles/editor` on the project.

Reference:

[Creating an API key](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#creating_an_api_key)

Answer (score 0):

You now need the role `roles/serviceusage.apiKeysAdmin`, according to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#managing_api_keys